# clearInterval() not working in ajax in php with both get and post methods called on submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, setinterval, clearinterval

I am using setInterval and then unable to clearInterval in my code. Please see the code
I am getting the value of complete and it is true and also entering the if statement but clearInterval still not working. I am tired and trying for last 10 hours but not find the bug. I checking the console.log and it is not stopping the interval.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var complete = false;
    var Interval;

    jQuery( "#form" ).submit(function() {
        Interval = setInterval(get, 100);
        post();
        return false;
    });

    function post(){

        var url = "my/url/here";

        var data = {
        'action': 'action/here',
        'name': 'value'
        };
        jQuery.post(url, data, function(response) {
            jQuery("#emails").html(response);
        }).done(function() {
        //alert( "second success" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
        //alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function() {
         complete = true;   
        //alert( "finished" );
        });

    } // End post()
    function get(){

        var url = "url/goes/here";

        if(complete == true){
            clearInterval(Interval);
        }
        var data = {
            'action': 'action/here',
        };

        jQuery.get(url, data, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            jQuery("#progress").html(response);     
        });

    } // End get()

});
```

### here is the original code below. ajax call is working fine but clearInterval() not working

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".juee_emails_row").hide();

    var juee_complete = false;
    var juee_Interval;

    jQuery( "#juee_form" ).submit(function() {
        jQuery(".juee_emails_row").show();
        juee_Interval = setInterval(juee_get, 100);
        juee_post();
        return false;
    });

    function juee_post(){
        var data = {
        'action': 'juee_get_emails',
        'juee_data_option': jQuery('input[name=juee_data_option]:checked', '#juee_form').val()
        };
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        jQuery("#juee_emails_td").html(response);
        }).done(function() {
        //alert( "second success" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
        //alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function() {
         juee_complete = true;  
        //alert( "finished" );
        });

    } // End juee_post()
    function juee_get(){
        if(juee_complete == true){
            clearInterval(juee_Interval);
        }
        var data = {
            'action': 'juee_progress',
        };

        jQuery.get(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        console.log(response + " email found");
        jQuery("#juee_progress_td").html("");
        jQuery("#juee_progress_td").html(response);     
    });

    } // End juee_get()

});
</script>
```

Comment: If you uncomment the `alert( "finished" );`, does that show up? I also trust that you made sure that you're not getting any error messages in the console.

Comment: no the script working fine. and alert( "finished" ); also popup and no error displaying. the get and post working fine also. but i dont know why clearInterval not working

Comment: I just put your code in a fiddle and it seems to cancel the interval just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6j41hp3c/1/ - there is one extra request due to the fact there's no `return` after the clear but apart from that it seems to work fine.

Comment: if i replace 
if(complete == true){
            clearInterval(Interval);
        }
to 
clearInterval(Interval);
then clearInterval works

Comment: Is your problem that one extra request after it's done, or does it keep making requests indefinitely?

Comment: if(complete == true){ clearInterval(Interval); console.log("its showing")} but clearInterval() not working. and function get is calling indefinitely

Comment: how can i show you original code any link where i paste it?

Comment: You can post it in your question. I thought you already did.